# Add the number of columns that have a value above a certain value pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have the following toy model, `df`:

```
product    customer1    customer2    customer3      
apple           40           110          120
banana         200           150          180
coconut         10             5           25
daq            120            10           30
eclair          45           190           35
```

I would like to add a column to `df` that counts the number of customers that bought at least a hundred of the items listed:

```
product    customer1    customer2    customer3   atleast100    
apple           40           110          120             2
banana         200           150          180             3
coconut         10             5           25             0
daq            120            10           30             1
eclair          45           190           35             1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':   ['apple', 'banana', 'coconut', 'daq', 'eclair'],
                   'customer1': [40, 200, 10, 120, 45],
                   'customer2': [110, 150, 5, 10, 190],
                   'customer3': [120, 180, 25, 30, 35]})
# among the customer columns, count the number of values greater or equal to 100 in each row
df['atleast100'] = df.filter(like='customer').ge(100).sum(1)
print(df)
   product  customer1  customer2  customer3  atleast100
0    apple         40        110        120           2
1   banana        200        150        180           3
2  coconut         10          5         25           0
3      daq        120         10         30           1
4   eclair         45        190         35           1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
df['atleast100'] = df[df.columns[1:]].gt(100).sum(axis=1)
print(df)

   product  customer1  customer2  customer3  atleast100
0    apple         40        110        120           2
1   banana        200        150        180           3
2  coconut         10          5         25           0
3      daq        120         10         30           1
4   eclair         45        190         35           1
```